# How to get offsetHeight, scrollHeight in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a directive in which I need three values-

1. scrollTop
2. offsetHeight
3. scrollHeight

   ```
   projectModule.directive('scroller', function ($window) {
   return {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
       var rawElement = angular.element($window);
       angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
           var scrollTop = rawElement.scrollTop();
           var offsetHeight = rawElement.offsetHeight;
           var scrollHeight = rawElement.scrollHeight;
           console.log(scrollTop + " ," + offsetHeight + " ," + scrollHeight);
           scope.$apply();
           });
       };
   });
   ```

I can get scrollTop directly by using rawElement.scrollTop() function, but How to get offsetHeight and scrollHeight of that element?

I want to apply that logic-

```
if ((rawElement.scrollTop + rawElement.offsetHeight + 5) >= rawElement.scrollHeight) {
    scope.$apply();    //For infinite scrolling
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to make use of `$document` service instead, since you actually need `document.body.scrollHeight` and `document.body.offsetHeight`. So

```
var offsetHeight = $document[0].body.offsetHeight;
var scrollHeight = $document[0].body.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use getBoundingClientRect if $el is the actual DOM element?

```
var top = $el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNLMe/1/)

You could also try using

```
$el.prop('offsetTop')
```