# How to find out the offsetHeight without inserting into the DOM (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the height that I have created , but I do not want to insert it into the house, I need just the height of this element which I will insert.

```
var elm = angular.element(`<div>{{text}}</div>`);
var elmScope = $rootScope.$new();
elmScope.text = 'foo bar';
var compileElement = $compile(elm)(elmScope);
//without this
//console.log(document.querySelector('.app').appendChild(compileElement[0]))
console.log(compileElement[0]);
console.log(compileElement[0].offsetHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/8805/

Comment: I really don't think this is possible - the element dimensions are only calculated when added to DOM. Try adding element somewhere beyond the screen and after calculations remove it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get offsetHeight, scrollHeight in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375793/how-to-get-offsetheight-scrollheight-in-angularjs)